# Old cat flea allergy dermatitis.

Tags: cats, skin-condition, fleas

When I scratch around my cats spine, he immediatly starts licking the air.As my vet said, this is obvious sign of a flea allergy. Advantix multi was the solution, as two days later, and for the entire time he was on the medication, he did not react this way.

As cats do, he got older and the same treatment does not have the same effect. He seems to still be affected by the dermatitis at his older age. Is this common?  He is on a high dose and can't go higher. Is there anything I can do to make him more comfortable?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try a new topical flea medication. Advantage stopped working for my cat and I switched to [Comfortis](https://www.comfortis.com/) which has continued to work really well for the past 2 years. Brushing your cat will also help and he may enjoy the extra attention. If his skin is flaky, you can make a solution of [colloidal oatmeal](https://www.tatcha.com/tatcha-institute/colloidal-oatmeal-benefits-for-the-skin/) in a basin of warm water. Soak a piece of old tee-shirt in the solution and wipe down his coat, rinsing out the rag often in clean, warm water and then dunking it again in the oatmeal solution. Try to get down to his skin and remove any flaky patches with the wipe.

My cat tolerates this well as long as the wipe is not too wet, just damp. You needn't rinse and it's safe for him to lick his coat afterward. There are a number of treatments and supplements you can look into if the situation doesn't improve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no specialist with regards to cat health. Among the best methods to make certain ticks and flicks keep off your beloved pet is via utilizing an easy but efficient flea collar.

BUT, pet cats are incredibly sensitive to chemical substances, therefore they could be specifically sensitive to flea collars. You can see the [list of collar here](http://petcomments.com/best-flea-collars-for-cats/). Perhaps you can decide on something organic and natural rather than standard insecticides. Organic flea collars consist of substances may prevent fleas via scent or poison fleas without posing a harming risk to cats.

The ultimate way to avoid fleas in cats is through making use of prescription flea preventatives created for them. Maybe certain breed of cat will not suitable to attach a flea collar or maybe it depends on how your cat will react to the certain chemical. Your veterinarian can assist you to pick which product is most effective for you as well as your problem.